# Alteryx : How to remove columns with specific names?

Tags: workflow, alteryx

I am trying to figure out how to **remove a column with a specific name** when i read a excel TSV in Alteryx?

Below is the sample **tsv data** that i have received

`name   given_name  family_name email   default_email_language  id  deactivated blocked incargo created_at  logins_count    last_login  last_ip locked_ips  tags    Apple   Banana  Grapes  Pineapple   fruit1  fruit2
AB CD   AB  CD  abcd@mail.com   x   1234    YES YES YES creationdate    23  logindate   ipinfo  X   x   YES NO  NO  NO  NO  NO
EF GH   EF  GH  efgh@mail.com   x   2345    NO  NO  YES creationdate        logindate   ipinfo  X   x   NO  YES YES YES NO  NO`

---

I wanted to remove the column which are named as `default_email_language`, `id`, `last_ip`, `incargo`.

I understand that i can do the same by select function, but the issue is that the data may change further, like this is the data for fruit vendor, i may have the data which have the vegetable vendors separately. Moreover, the column arrangement may change further as well.

In that case I have to create multiple workflows. I wanted to automate this a little bit so that whenever the data set is changing, it just picks up the name and then remove the entire column from the data. PS - The column data is completely irrelevant and may or maynot have any data as well.

I can further explain if required. For a start i need to just remove these specific columns from the data. I tried searching in the alteryx community but was of no luck. Anybody who can give me a reference as well would also do.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

With a [Dynamic Select](https://help.alteryx.com/current/DynamicSelect.htm) set to Select Via Formula, you can set up a formula to select fields where [Name] != "default_email_language" AND [Name] != "id" etc. If you want to make it more dynamic, you can set up a field that has the field names you don't want to include and just say [Name] != [Ignore these names field].